# convert tar to zip with stdout/stdin

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, pipe, tar

How can I convert a tar file to zip using stdout/stdin?

-@ takes a list of files from stdin, tar -t provides that but doesn't actually extract the files. Using -xv provides me a list of files and extracts it to disk but I'm trying to avoid touching the disk.

Something *like* the following but obviously the below will not produce the same file structure.

```
tar -xf somefile.tar -O | zip somefile.zip -
```

I can do it by temporarily writing files to disk but I'm trying to avoid that - I'd like to use pipes only.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I'm not aware of "standard" utility doing the conversion on the fly.

But similar question has been discussed over [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146264/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-zip-to-a-tar-without-extracting-it-to-the-filesystem) using a python libs, which has a simple structure, probably you can adapt the script to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about the tool that performs direct conversion. As a workaround, if your files are not extremely huge, you can extract the tar archive into a `tmpfs`-mounted directory (or similar), that is, the filesystem that resides completely in memory and don't work with disk. It should be much faster than extracting into the disk folder.